# SQL Reporting Services - Cryptic Warnings

Tags: .net, reporting-services, rdlc

I'm using reporting services in local processing mode.

I'm setting the report data to a Dataset pulled from a sql database.

When I come to render the report I get two warnings:

1. The data set ‘PPA_Dev’ contains a definition for the Field ‘EMail’. This field is missing from the returned result set from the data source.
2. The data set ‘PPA_Dev’ contains a definition for the Field ‘EMail’. The data extension returned an error during reading the field. There is no data for the field at position 9.

What I'm seeing in the generated report is the email column empty.

Why might this be happening?

**UPDATE**

The sql that was generating the dataset was returning the correct information.

In the end I fiddled around with the rdlc file in notepad, broke the whole report, reverted the code and it now works correctly. No idea why it was broken, no idea why it's fixed, it's all very frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the dataset definition includes a field called "Email" which is not being returned from your source query, but it's difficult to be sure without more information.

Could you amend the question to include the SQL used to generate the dataset?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. For me, the RDLC looked fine. Eventually I noticed that that dataset parameters were listed in a different order than in the stored procedure. When I reordered them in the dataset to match the SP, all was well. I would add this to your list of checks when encountering this error.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem. When I checked the rdlc in the Visual Studio Xml Editor I found that the fields being complained about (EMail in the original question above) were wrongly specified in the 'DataSets/DataSet/Fields' section of the rdlc. Removing these fields corrected the problem.

I had previously changed the Datasource object and it would seem that the rdlc dataset was not updated with those fields that had been changed.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue when creating a report against a SharePoint list. If the column in the list was empty, then the column was not returned in the query response. I found an [old post on www.msbicentral.com](http://www.msbicentral.com/Resources/Articles/tabid/88/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/108/SSRS-Unexplained-Warning-This-field-is-missing-from-the-returned-result-set-from-the-data-source-And-Checking-a-Field-for-Null-Exception.aspx#Comment25374) that helped to resolve the problem.

In the report properties, add a new function definition to the Custom code section:

```
Function NullAsEmpty(ByRef F As Field) As String
    If F.IsMissing Then
        Return ""
    Else
        If F.Value Is Nothing Then
            Return ""
        Else
            Return F.Value
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Add a variable that can be used in place of the actual field. In my case I added a variable `reason` defined as `=Code.NullAsEmpty(Fields!Reason)`. Then in the report replace occurrences of the original field with the new variable.

Answer (score 2):

Had that exact error message and noticed (thanks to dkritz post above) I had fields in my dataset that were not in my final SQL select. So I deleted those fields from the dataset and voila.

A bit of history - The original dataset was using query text. I delete that dataset and created another (using the same name for the ds). This new one referenced a stored procedure, some fields varied from the original. I think because the ds was named the same, it pulled fields from the original ds and combined it with new ds. The error was referring to the fields of the old ds.

Answer (score 1):

Directly binding the table with SSRS report works fine. But when I used the same table in a Stored Procedure for that report has thrown

```
[rsMissingFieldInDataSet] The dataset ‘DataSet1’ contains a definition for the Field ‘Currency’. This field is missing from the returned result set from the data source.
```

Adding

```
SET ARITHABORT ON;
```

in the beginning of the SP fixed this issue.

Environment: Visual Studio 2008, SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

For me, a single quote mark caused the problem.

> ```
>    <Field Name="Field1">
>       <DataField>Field1"</DataField>
>       <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
>     </Field>
> ```

Correct the line containing `<DataField>Field1"</DataField>` as:

> ```
>    <Field Name="Field1">
>       <DataField>Field1</DataField>
>       <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
>     </Field>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but for SSAS source. There was a field that was filtered as a null column, so it wasn't shown in the executed output, but this field was in the `Fields` list. The order of the fields was also mixed in comparison to fields in the source query.

What I did was a mix of the other people tips:

- Remove this field with null values
- Change the order of the fields to the same as in source query
- **RESTART** Visual Studio - because even though I did the steps above, the error was still appearing. After restarting VS, the warnings magically disappeared!